# How to hide the action bar and get full screen with Theme.AppCompat.Light

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appcompat

How to hide the action bar and get full screen with Theme.AppCompat.Light on Android 2.x? I had tried following code on styles.xml:

```
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```

It doens't work. How to solve without use java code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That configuration works. Just make sure you are adding the correct `Theme` from the correct styles.xml (not from `values-vXX` folder styles) file to your Activity in manifest.xml file.

Also make sure your `Activity` does not extend `ActionBarActivity`, but `FragmentActivity`, as you do not want the `ActionBar` to show.